# Aligned output from arraylist Java

Tags: java, arraylist, output

I am a newbie for Java , I just wanna ask something about how to output data from arraylist with align format such as:

```
CustomerNo      Name            PhoneNo            Status
         1       Ali         0177788901         Normal
```

I try many method such as "/t":

```
for(int i = 0; i <= formatCus.size()-1; i++){
            System.out.printf(formatCus.get(i) + "\t");
         }
         System.out.println("");
        for(int i = 0; i <= cusData.size()-1; i++){
            System.out.print(cusData.get(i) + "\t");
         }
```

and also "%15d":

```
for(int i = 0; i <= formatCus.size()-1; i++){
            System.out.printf("%15d",formatCus.get(i));
         }
         System.out.println("");
        for(int i = 0; i <= cusData.size()-1; i++){
            System.out.printf("%15d",cusData.get(i));
         }
```

but not of them working so I want to ask for help.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You should use printf also in  System.out.print(cusData.get(i) + "\t");

Comment: The format method of the String class gives you a different way to construct output lines where the columns line up.  %20s right justifies a String, while %-20s left justifies a String.

Comment: It also looks like you're storing your data as a bag of items instead of as a proper class. This makes your task unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: Not sure why you would want the `phoneNumber` column to be aligned differently than the `CustomerNo` and `Name` columns?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- How can I storing my data as a proper class ? If needed I can send you my data.

Comment: @Joe I will try this , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you should really store each Customer in a [class](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_classes.asp), regardless, here is a fragile solution based on your current attempt:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private static final String COLUMN_FORMAT = "%15s";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> columnNames = List.of("CustomerNo", "Name", "PhoneNo", "Status");
        List<String> customerData = List.of("1", "Ali", "0177788901", "Normal",
                                            "2", "Bill", "0277788901", "Good");
        for (String column : columnNames) {
            System.out.printf(COLUMN_FORMAT, column);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < customerData.size(); i += 4) {
            for (int j = i; j < i + 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf(COLUMN_FORMAT, customerData.get(j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 CustomerNo           Name        PhoneNo         Status
          1            Ali     0177788901         Normal
          2           Bill     0277788901           Good
```